# Docker entrypoint "not found"

Tags: docker, gitlab-ci

**TL;DR**
Why does my Docker image work when I build it locally with `$ docker build -t broker .`, but when it's built in GitLab CI, I get `bash: line 1: /bin/broker: not found`?

**Background / troubleshooting**
I'm using GitLab CI to deploy new releases of my system using Helm for Kubernetes.

I just changed my Dockerfiles to use `alpine:3.7` instead of `golang:1.9.2`, since it's just running the built binary and not executing go code, bringing my image size down from ~800MB to around ~24MB.

The problem I run into now is that when the image is built in GitLab CI, I get the following error from the container:

```
bash: line 1: /bin/broker: not found
```

I've tried [changing `ENTRYPOINT` to `CMD`](https://github.com/docker-library/openjdk/issues/94#issuecomment-276083715) to make sure that the binary is run as shell, but it just changes the error to this:

```
/bin/sh: /bin/broker: not found
```

If I build the image locally and run it, everything works as expected. Also, from the GitLab CI logs, I get this:

```
$ go build
$ mv $SERVICE_NAME $CI_PROJECT_DIR
Uploading artifacts...
broker: found 1 matching files                        
Uploading artifacts to coordinator... ok            id=1234 
responseStatus=201 Created token=ABC123
```

This means that my binary was successfully built, just like with the old image. Next, I get this:

```
[...]
Step 3/4 : COPY ./broker /bin
 ---> 50d04cbbc81c
Step 4/4 : CMD /bin/broker
 ---> Running in c48a73351599
[...]
```

... meaning that the binary was successfully downloaded as an artifact and copied onto the image.

My Dockerfile looks like this:

```
# This file is intended for use with the GitLab CI tool where the binary has already been built.
FROM alpine:3.7

# Make sure we have some basic dev tools.
RUN \
    apk --update add curl bash nano && \
    rm -r /var/cache/apk/*

# The binary is built and downloaded to the current directory by GitLab CI.
COPY ./broker /bin
RUN chmod +x /bin/broker

# Run the program.
CMD /bin/broker
```

I use a fully qualified path, so the `$PATH` var shouldn't matter.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: try with `ADD broker /bin/broker` instead of `COPY`. From the error it seems that something is wrong with the `/bin/broker`

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Turns out the problem was that I didn't build for Alpine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some luck in phrasing a better Google search, I found the solution.

When running `go build`, I, of course, build for the local Linux, which doesn't run on Alpine.

The solution was to change `go build` in my GitLab CI file to [`CC=$(which musl-gcc) go build --ldflags '-w -linkmode external -extldflags "-static"'`](https://www.reddit.com/r/golang/comments/4cxrcv/whats_the_proper_way_to_build_golang_apps_for/), which builds properly for Alpine.

[`musl-gcc` is included in the `musl-tools`](https://github.com/alexcrichton/backtrace-rs/issues/34), so to install it, run `apt-get -y musl-tools`.